# Image Preloading Challenge

Tags: javascript, php, image, caching, preload

My goal is to start preloading all of the website images for a large photo gallery website on the front page (index.php) without it being perceived by the user.  If the user clicks into the site (home.php) before all the images are loaded, which will definitely happen, the preloading process should continue invisible to the user.  And if the user clicks to other pages (portfolio.php, etc.) the preloading process again continues.  The idea is that hopefully with each new page, the process will not completely re-start because many images will already be cached, and the user will not have to wait while all the images preload.

Currently I am loading all of the images with html img elements that are inside a div with style="display:none".  The img elements are delay-loaded with Javascript (LazyLoad technique) so that the page loads first without waiting on the img.

Is there a better way to do this?

```
<?php
foreach ($imageArray as $image) {

    //code to find $fullImagePath.......

    echo "<div><img u=\"image\" src=\" \" data-src=\"$fullImagePath\" height=\"100\"; width=\"100\"; class=\"lazy\" /></div>";

} // end of loop

?>          

<script type="text/javascript">

$(window).bind("load", function() {
    var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        $("img.lazy").each(function(){
            $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('data-src'));
        })
    }, 500);
});

</script>
```

Comment: Just start from the beginning every time. It will quickly skip over the cached images.

Answer (score 0):

While you're right in triggering it from setTimeout after the window onload event, I'm not convinced that this is adding a lot of value.

Unless you are using localstorage (and even if you are) cache size is **very** limited on a mobile device (and bandwidth usage=powerusage).

I would see if its possible to pre-fetch the images (and other content?) from the pages the user can navigate to from the current page (e.g. loading them in hidde iframes?)